# Problem with DocuSign, migrating from dev environment to prod environent (Go-Live)

Tags: php, api, docusignapi

**For my ticket to DocuSign support (Case #: 05646003, Account #: 7824722-na2) that I got no answer for it, I mentioned my issues here:**

Generally, the Issues that I have:

- When I activate the account by the invitation link, an Integration Key will be added to my account but sometimes it disappears. Also, a button that switches the users sometimes appears. This condition takes a long time for us to track the issues (My account is not a premium account and I am just invited by another premium account)
- I use these APIs to access the envelopes:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxxx/envelopes?from_date=2019-12-20
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/envelopes?from_date=2019-12-20
```

I have added 22 envelopes there but when I try to "Submit for Go-Live" it says that I don't have 20+ demo transactions.

- I am using those APIs with my Account ID. I followed the instruction to generate an access token using the integration key and the client id, but the code didn't work for "Authorization - Bearer".
- I also couldn't find any working instructions that describe "how to migrate from Demo to Production" with details. I have checked all of those pages in the documentation but all of them didn't work.

I have read the documentation but the solutions that are mentioned there didn't work for me and I need details for solving these issues.

**I should note that currently, my codes are working in the Dev environment.**

I used this link to generate the code:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=1b8f72eb-8667-4e0e-...&redirect_uri=https://site.test
```

The result was:

```
https://site.test/?code=eyJ0e...
```

Now I need to know what are my:
- Account ID
- Access Token
- Base URL

Comment: You say you've added 22 envelopes - Did you do these through the Web Console, or via your integration? When the documentation says "20+ demo transactions", it's referring to API calls on your integration key.

Comment: 1. I generated the access token with this link:
https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
2. Then I sent 22 envelopes

3. At last, I sent this POST request to check the envelopes with this URL:
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/8907146/envelopes?from_date=2019-12-20
Note: 8907146 was my Account ID
Note: I also set Authorization to header "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ..."

Comment: The Access Token Generator is not valid for Go Live - it uses a DocuSign-owned integration key instead of your own. The token generator is intended for simple testing / quick proof-of-concept apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE: You cannot use the token generator that is on the developer center website when you go Live. Please ensure you actually use tokens from Production when you authenticate to your app in production.**

Masoud, for help with going live you can email to :
go-live@docusign.com

The general documentation about Go Live is here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live

You can find further information here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-steps

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I have checked them before. In the section "20+ Test Transactions" of the second article, it says:
`The 20 test transactions do not need to all be create and send envelope requests but rather can be requests to generate signing URLs, download document(s), get form field data, and so on.`
Is that mean, creating and sending envelopes are not counted?

Comment: it is counted, but you cannot use the token from the generator. You must use an OAauth flow